# gspread append_row don't add from col A, starts from J

Tags: python, gspread

I am making a score keeper program. I want to add a row with append_row, but for some reason it doesn't start from A, instead it starts from J in the worksheet.
Right now this is the code of the button:

```
Button:
    text: "+1"
    on_press: root.ss_sheet.append_row([str(root.localtime.hour)+ ':' + str(root.localtime.minute), spinner1_id.text, goal_1_id.text, assist_1_id.text])
```

I was giving the worksheet a "header" with append_row and it was working fine on a different button. Any idea why is it shifted to the right so much at this "+1" button? Using the button multiple times it always starts at J at the next row. It would be perfect if it'd start at A.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, the issue is I made empty cells in the first row (like this: Game Time, Team Get, Goal, Assist, [Empty Cell], Games Start...etc), and the empty cell is the start point of the append_row's first column.